# Get select2 4.0.0 ajax response data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have more fields associated to a select2 beside id and text and I can't get them the way I usually did in version 3.5.2 (I'm using version 4.0.0 now):

```
var id = $('#something').select2('data').id;
var name= $('#something').select2('data').text;
var email= $('#something').select2('data').email;
```

I already found who to get id and text:

```
var id = $('#something').val();
var name = $('#something').text();
```

But I must get the other fields associated and I'm not finding the way.
Note: The select2 is filled via a ajax request to a database table and I already checked that the json data is correctly returned with all the data.

Comment: Can you show the html ?

Comment: <select id="something" name="something" style="width: 320px"></select>